# Trying to use AsyncTask to update server periodically

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have a method that need to update its status periodically to the server.

I am using AsyncTask to run the HTTP call in background.

> **PROBLEM**: In onPostExecute method upon checking AsyncTask.getStatus, It show the previous task still running which is causing the error.
>
> **ERROR**: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot execute task: the task is already running.
>
> **DIFFERENT STRATEGIES USED TO SOLVE THE PROBLEM BUT NONE IS WORKING**

```
     1. Before Relaunching AsyncTask, checked the status, it is showing the thread is RUNNING.
     2. Called the AsyncTask.cancel(true), immediately before calling the AsyncTask.execute if it is still running. It turns out AsyncTask still RUNNING and taking more than 3 mins to get cancel.
```

NOTE: I have checked many similar questions here, but haven't found helpful.

> I would really appredicae if any one of you guys give me an example to solve this issue, Thanks a Million in advance......

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements AsyncResponse{

ConnectServer asyncTask =new ConnectServer();

  

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   
   asyncTask.delegate = this;
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  
   //Start updating server using below method
    loop();
     
}

   public void processFinish(String output){

    //this you will received result fired from async class of onPostExecute(result) method.
    //Log.v(TAG, output);
    if(output != null){
        
        //not using this at this point
        
    }
  }
  
   //Method that will call Async method to reach server
 
public void loop(){

      TextView b = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mField);
       String str;
    try {
        str = asyncTask.execute(true).get();
        b.setText(str);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }



    // START SERVER CONNECTION       
    class ConnectServer extends AsyncTask<Boolean, String, String> {         
       public AsyncResponse delegate=null;   
       public int i = 0;
       private Activity activity;         
       public void MyAsyncTask(Activity activity) {
            this.activity = activity;
        }


       @Override
       protected String doInBackground(Boolean... params) {
             String result = null;
             StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
               try {
                 // http post
                 HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                 
                 HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet("http://192.168.0.21:8080");
                 HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                 if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200) {
                     Log.d("GPSApp", "Server encountered an error");
             }

                 BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF8"));
                 sb = new StringBuilder();
                 sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");
                 String line = null;
    
                 while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                   sb.append(line + "\n");
             }

                 result = sb.toString();
                 
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
            }
              return result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
             

            TextView mField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mField);
            mField.setText(result+i);
           
                
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10000);
                //asyncTask =new ConnectServer();
                 i++;
                String str = asyncTask.execute(true).get();
                mField.setText(str+i);
                 
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

         }

         protected void onPreExecute() {}
     }
   }
```

Comment: So the problem is (if I've understand you right) - you want to relaunch asynctask but the previous task is still running, have you tried to call cancel?

Comment: Hello my friend, yes you have understood right, Iam trying to relaunch the asyncTask, and YES I tried to cancel the it before relaunching, it is not working either. Do you have any other suggestion to make call to the server?

Answer (score 0):

Call [getStatus()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#getStatus%28%29) to get the status of AsyncTask. If the status is [AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.Status.html), cancel it.

Comment: Dear @jungleboy I have checked the status and called the method asyncTask.cancel(true) if still running, this is taking long time to cancel it like more than a min. Do you have any other suggestion to make call to the server? Thanks..